# shortcut to change layer/add via while routing in Altium doesn' t work

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, routing, via

I'm trying to change my tracks during routing to pass from bottom to the top, or from top to bottom using +/- buttons, but neither numerical buttons neither +/- buttons from keyboard buttons are doing anything.

I see there is people who face this problem but I don't see how they finally solved the situation. When I  go to DXP menu, customize shorcuts, I found next layer and previous layer aptions linked to "minus" and "plus" buttons.

If I'm not drawing tracks, this commands is changing the shown layer for the next or the previous one. But it' s not adding any via or changing the track I'm drawing.

When I press the change layer button while a track is being drawed, the selected track doesn' t change the color and any via is painted. Its color stills being the current layer color, it doesn't change because it can't change from current layer to the next or to the previous. I don't know what's the problem, or how to pass the track from top layer to bottom layer with a via automatically as it's seen at examples and tutorials.

What are exactly the combination of buttons and commands to get the desired behavior?
I think I'm doing something wrong, I'm doing this way:

1.- draw a track until the pcb point of change,

2.- once there I click with left button (mouse) the track one time.

3.-Here, I press the change layer button.

4.- Here I was hopping to change the track layer. Instead of this, the current layer doesn' t change,  neither via is appearing, when I follow drawing the track it can only still drawing within the origin track layer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try pressing change layer before left clicking to o choose the location.

Comment: Great! I think it was the right answer. Now it works.

Comment: OK, I will post as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing this way:
>
> 1.- draw a track until the pcb point of change,
>
> 2.- once there I click with left button (mouse) the track one time.
>
> 3.-Here, I press the change layer button.
>
> 4.- Here I was hopping to change the track layer.

You need to swap steps 2 and 3.

When you click the "change layer" button it will (IIRC) produce a via on the end of your track, which you can then move around where you want it before left-clicking to choose its final location.